# What are node invariants and how do I use them to 'prune the search tree' in my program checking for graph isomorphisms?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, networkx, invariants, isomorphism

For a project, I'm writing a python program that works with networkx to create a NAUTY style isomorphism checking program.  My program is based on the introduction to Nauty to be found [here](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/Introduction.html) and works as follows:

Take two graphs G and H and color the nodes according to their degree.
Run a color refinement algorithm that refines the coloring of the graph based on the neighbors of each node in a color class. This pair (G', H') becomes the 'root' of my search tree, on which i'll use a DFS algorithm.  Next, I individualize a node in G' that belongs to the smallest color class with more than one element in it, and produce, using a branching method, new pairs of trees (G'', H''), (G'', H'''), ... (G'', H^(k)) (k depends on the size of the color class, for example if in g for the color class red: [1,2,3] are the red nodes in G, and [5,6,7] are the red nodes in H, then i have to make a branch for the search tree for the pair 1:5, 1:6, 1:7, and open new branches to visit in my search tree later). And there is the rub!  My tree grows too big, too fast - and its because i'm not using the node invariants described in the 'node invariants and pruning' part of the above mentioned link.

Can someone perhaps explain a few examples of node invariants that I can use?  On StackExchange i've not found much helpful here.  I assume and use the fact that my node colors are node invariants, but for strong regular graphs, that doesn't always bring me much.  Any ideas?